# lossing data when exit from function at c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a problem using the data base "map".
I am writting a progrem that implement BFS (breadth first search) at graphs.
In oreder to keep the "key" (string) and the "value" (Vertex- a class I created)
I use :
    `map<string, Vertex*> graph`

"graph" is a field at class "Graph" that include some functions.
One of the functions is " void addv(string& key)" - her goal is to add a new
Vertex to the map. here a copy of the function:

```
void Graph::addv(string& key) // add vertex to the graph
{

// initilazited the map by values
  string tempKey = key;
  Vertex v(tempKey);
  v.initialize(tempKey); // at the begining, the color of all vertexes is 
  //"white".
  Vertex * p =&v;
  graph.insert(pair<string,Vertex*>(tempKey, &v));  

}
```

From the the main program I run this program:

```
int main()
{
  Graph g;
  string v1, v2, e1,e2 ,name;
  cout << "enter vertexes" << endl;
  cin >> v1;
  cin >> v2;
  g.addv(v1); g.addv(v2);
}
```

My problem is the "return values" of the function.
At the running the program my input value were: v1= 'A', v2= 'B'.
When I debug the program I noticed that when the process get to mention fuction,
the value of the "graph" nearly to exit from the function were as you can see
at the picture below:

[image: before]

But at final step of the process at the fuction, the values change as you can see
at this picture:

[image: after]

As you can see the "key" value at parmeter "second" change to " " instead of "A".

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inserting a pointer to a variable with local storage duration. It is the nature of such variables to get cleaned up again when the function is exited and you end with a dangling pointer.

To solve the issue, either *copy* the struct into the map (`std::map<std::string, Vertex>`, note the dropped astrisk!) or create the values on heap (`Vertex* v = new Vertex(tempKey);`).

Answer (score 0):

I think one issue is that as soon as any `addv` call terminates, the `Vertex` that was allocated (on the stack) is destroyed, and its memory deallocated. You'd probably want to allocate it on the heap instead (using `new` for example, but nowadays "using `new`" should be replaced by `using (the right kind of) smart pointer, in that case, probably a std::unique_ptr that you create with std::make_unique.